# Laravel 5.4: How to order by count(column) in eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display the names of assignee arranged by the most tickets `assigned_to`.

```
$accesses = Access::where('state','=','Assigned');

$all = Report::where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
               ->union($accesses)
               ->orderBy('count(assigned_to)') //THIS IS WRONG
               ->get();
```

Comment: Inside your orderBy use `DB::raw()` of laravel to count.

Comment: kindly clarify your answer?

Comment: eg: `->orderBy(DB::raw('query here'))`

Comment: Can you please post your result array/collection for above query

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `DB::raw` to get it

```
$all = Report::where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(reports.assigned_to) as assigned_to'))
            ->union($accesses)
            ->orderBy('assigned_to','DESC') 
            ->get();
```

Comment: Or you can use `selectRaw`

Comment: but it will only count the assigned_to of reports table, I want to be able to count assigned_to of the union'd tables.

Comment: so pass the query as you are passing for assigned to, the same way you are doing it here

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$accesses = Access::where('state','=','Assigned');

$all = Report::where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
                ->union($accesses)
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(assigned_to)'),'DESC') 
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$all = Report::where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
             ->select(DB::raw('count(reports.assigned_to) as assigned_to'))
            ->union($accesses)
            ->orderBy('assignedto','DESC') 
            ->get();
```

Comment: but it will only count the assigned_to of reports table, I want to be able to count assigned_to of the union'd tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
$all = Report::where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(reports.assigned_to) as assigned_to'),DB::raw('count(access.assigned_to) as assigned_to_access'))
            ->leftjoin('access','report.access.id','=','access.id')
            ->union($accesses)
            ->orderBy('assigned_to','DESC')
            ->orderBy('assigned_to_access','DESC') 
            ->get();
```

Hope this help for you !!!